# MYSQL Query multiple attributes Aliases

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this MYSQL query to pull back information:

```
SELECT product_table.id, connector_table.id_two,
attribute_table.attribute, details_table.detail, det2.detail, det3.detail, det4.detail, det5.detail, det6.detail,att7.attribute,det7.detail
FROM  `product_table` 
LEFT JOIN connector_table ON product_table.id = connector_table.id_one
LEFT JOIN attribute_table ON connector_table.id_two = attribute_table.id
LEFT JOIN details_table ON connector_table.id_three = details_table.id
LEFT JOIN connector_table AS conn2 ON connector_table.id_one = conn2.id_one
LEFT JOIN details_table AS det2 ON conn2.id_three = det2.id
LEFT JOIN connector_table AS conn3 ON connector_table.id_one = conn3.id_one
LEFT JOIN details_table AS det3 ON conn3.id_three = det3.id
LEFT JOIN connector_table AS conn4 ON connector_table.id_one = conn4.id_one
LEFT JOIN details_table AS det4 ON conn4.id_three = det4.id
LEFT JOIN connector_table AS conn5 ON connector_table.id_one = conn5.id_one
LEFT JOIN details_table AS det5 ON conn5.id_three = det5.id
LEFT JOIN connector_table AS conn6 ON connector_table.id_one = conn6.id_one
LEFT JOIN details_table AS det6 ON conn6.id_three = det6.id
LEFT JOIN connector_table AS conn7 ON connector_table.id_one = conn7.id_one
LEFT JOIN details_table AS det7 ON conn7.id_three = det7.id
LEFT JOIN attribute_table as att7 ON conn7.id_two = att7.id
WHERE exported =0
AND product_table.id =2
AND connector_table.id_two = 130
AND conn2.id_two = 152
AND conn3.id_two = 129
AND conn4.id_two = 43
AND conn5.id_two = 49
AND conn6.id_two = 130
AND conn7.id_two = 41
```

This pulls back information which i want on one row, the issue is anyone of the attributes ( the conn aliases) can have more than one of the same attribute and so it prints to more than one row.

is there any dynamic way to allow the query to pull back the attributes on one row even if they have more than one attribute?

Thanks

Comment: Convert the joins to `EXISTS` subqueries.

Comment: Did you look into the GROUP_CONCAT function?  Perhaps you should give a simplified example of your current output, and how you wish to put it into 1 row.

Comment: You can add `LIMIT 1` to the end of query to get only one ROW

Comment: the GROUP_CONCAT  function groups all of the column together which is better than what i had but i need each attribute in a different colmn

Comment: Given this query, you could change all `LEFT JOIN`s to `INNER JOIN`s and still get the same result.